# Having problem submitting a form without reload using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When i submit form it doesnot update value in database mysql.Its a form written in php.
here is my php and html. I want that the form should not reload and it must submit the changes in database without reloading the page and show preloader for 1 sec on submitting form.
HTML,PHP AND ACTION of form: Here action is the current page where this form is avalilable

**detail_customer.php**

```
<?php


$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "stinkspolitics_pl";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $pass, $dbname);



if (isset($_GET['detail_customer'])) {
    $quest_id = $_GET['detail_customer'];

    $get_quest = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE quest_id = '$quest_id'";
    $getting_quest = mysqli_query($conn, $get_quest);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getting_quest)) {
        $quest_title = $row['quest_title'];
        $category_id = $row['category_id'];
    }
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $quest_t = $_POST['quest_t'];

    $update = "UPDATE questions SET quest_title = '$quest_t' WHERE quest_id = '$quest_id'";
    $run_update = mysqli_query($conn, $update);
    if ($run_update) {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}

?>


<div class="recent-orders cust_det ">
    <h2> Customer Detail</h2>
    <div class="customer_detail">
        <form id="form-submit" action="./inc/detail_customer.php
        " method="POST" class="c_form animate__animated animate__fadeIn">



            <div class='alert alert-success'>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Your question has been submitted.
            </div>


            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong>Sorry!</strong> Your question has not been submitted.
            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cat_id" value="<?php echo $category_id  ?>" id="cat_id">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" name="quest_t" value="<?php echo $quest_title  ?>" id="quest_t">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>

                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input name="submit" type="hidden" />
                <input class="btn-primary submit-btn" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code
**index.js**

```
$("#form-submit").on("submit", function () {
    // e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: formData,
      success: function (data) {
        $(".alert-success").show();
        $(".alert-success").fadeOut(4000);
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
        $(".alert-danger").show();
        $(".alert-danger").fadeOut(4000);
        console.log(data);
      },
    });
    return false;
  });
```

Ajax Success Response But not updating data in mySQL

```
<div class="recent-orders cust_det ">
    <h2> Customer Detail</h2>
    <div class="customer_detail">
        <form id="form-submit" action="./inc/detail_customer.php" method="POST"
            class="c_form animate__animated animate__fadeIn">



            <div class='alert alert-success'>
                <strong>Success!</strong> Your question has been submitted.
            </div>


            <div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong>Sorry!</strong> Your question has not been submitted.
            </div>



            <div class="row">
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cat_id" value="<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable $category_id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_panel\inc\detail_customer.php</b> on line <b>62</b><br />
" id="cat_id">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" name="quest_t" value="<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable $quest_title in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\admin_panel\inc\detail_customer.php</b> on line <b>66</b><br />
" id="quest_t">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>

                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">Contact</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
                <div class="c_detail">
                    <label for="" class="form-labels">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="" id="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input name="submit" type="hidden" />
                <input class="btn-primary submit-btn" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the . concatenation operator for combining PHP variables and strings? title = ' . $quest . '?

Comment: No bro its not necessary. It works well and query is good because i have checked the query without ajax

Comment: it only problems when we try to submit it using ajax and no reload

Comment: To prevent form from default reload and make `e.preventDefault()` work you need to add `e` to the function `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Comment: Please do not "Throw code" in like your HTML Form which is a copy/paste from a Contact Form you found somewhere and just changed a couple of inputs leaving "Dead HTML" behind... Also where do you set $quest_id? Your naming etc is very confusing.

Comment: Question id is coming from $_GET

Comment: I am getting question id through $_GET because i want to use it in WHERE clause while updating form

Comment: Please add the filenames along with the extensions next to the code, so that we understand where each code snippet can be found.

Comment: I have added filenames above.

Comment: You still need to remove all that extra "JUNK" Html in your form and rename your labels to something sensible.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` will never evaluate to true, since there is no input element in the form with `name="submit"` (the button with name='submit' does not send the attribute by default).

Either change the condition:

`if (isset($_POST['quest_t'])) { ...`

Or, include an input element with `name='submit'`, for example:

`<input name="submit" type="hidden" />`

Also, make sure to move the $_POST check at the beginning of the file and ensure that no other code will be evaluated in the PHP file (e.g. the rest of the HTML code) if a POST request has been received.

Comment: I have editted question with new code and it still not works :(

Comment: An input with type submit is still not sending the name=submit key value pair

Comment: Add an input with type="hidden" and name="submit" and check again @MuhammadUzair

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Code updated above with changes.

Comment: There is already a Submit button in the Form with a Blank Name. So why would adding a "hidden" input with a name of "submit" be a good idea? Just change the existing submit input name="" to name="submit".

Comment: An input element with the `type` attribute set to submit, does not actually submit the name key/value pair. Since the PHP file was checking to see whether a name="submit" is being submitted, I suggested that he try this name attribute on another type of input element just to receive the key/value pair on the backend. This was meant as a quick debuggin advice. Further refactoring is needed on many parts of the code, but we have to start somewhere. @TimBrownlaw

Answer (score 0):

Just return false after at the end of the method.

jQuery has its own way of ensuring "preventDefault()" and it is just returning false from the  submit handler.

Full background on this here:

[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: i  have replaced button with <input class="btn-primary submit-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> but it is still not working with neither return false nethier by changing the button

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved. By changing path and then putting path of js file again.